# Creating responsive mobile menu, want to know how to stop prevetDefault() from affecting landscape view

Tags: jquery, mobile, responsive-design

I have created an accordion menu for mobile of the site I am building.

The problem I am having is that changing to landscape view triggers the normal site to display, maintaining the code generated from the mobile menu which uses preventDefault() to stop the links from the normal behavior of the desktop site.

Is there any way to restore the original desktop code when converting to the desktop site without page refresh?

I realize one option would be to enable the mobile menu for a larger screen size, such as 800px, however there are likely going to be circumstances where the screen size would change outside of the range on a mobile device (without refresh) therefore continuing this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be switching back and forth between desktop/mobile based on the current size of the screen. You don't want your users to go to mobile site just because they resized their browser. You should set mobile/desktop when the user enters and keep it set that way unless the user specifically asks for it to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Responsive design is based on the screen/browser size. It's intended to adapt to devices of various sizes. Unfortunately sometimes sizes overlap and can cause issues. Although essentially the mobile and desktop sites are not separate.

Comment: I ended up changing my mobile breakpoint from 480 to 640. I tried it on one of the larger mobile screens out there (galaxy S) and it maintains mobile in portrait and landscape. I was previously going off the stated screen resolutions for these devices, however in actual practice the resolution displayed is actually not the same. It must have something to do with more pixels but maintaining the same view-port size.